# Drawing knockout(single elimination) fixtures

Tags: football, tournaments

Okay so everyone, how can I draw a knockout fixture of matches of 24 teams? As the number of teams are even so there has to be no bye given. Also I do not require any seeding. Can someone please come with any ideas? [image: This is how I did]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You can do a single elimination knockout without byes *only* if the number of teams is an exact power of 2 (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc). With 24 teams, you've got to have a bye somewhere; the simplest solution in your case is just too have 8 byes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to the question. [image]

All credit to Philip Kendall.

Comment: That wouldn't be the normal way of doing it as you're "playing" bye vs bye in the first round. Take a traditional 1-32 bracket, put byes in slots 25-32 and then draw your 24 teams in the other slots.